Microsoft Edge lags for short bursts very frequently. What to look for in trying to fix this?
From time to time microsoft edge would just freeze. The window wouldn't respond to scrolling, typing, clicking anything. It would be unresponsive for a solid few seconds and then the response would come back suddenly.
I am using the stable version of edge. The RAM usage seems to be fine, i.e. SWAP isn't being used a lot, and the usage is well below full RAM.
Would appreciate any advice.
